# Program crashes in the second run, after the return 0 from main C++

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2015

I have built my own functions of strlen and strdup.
When i use my strdup in the first time it's okay, i close the window, run it again, then in the end of the program after the return 0 from the main the program crashes. VS just says that it triggered a breakpoint.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int MyStrlen(const char* str);
char* MyStrdup(const char* str);

int main()
{
    char *s1 = "Hello World!";
    char *s2 = MyStrdup(s1);

    cout << s1 << " , " << s2 << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


int MyStrlen(const char* str)
{
    register int iLength = 0;

    while (str[iLength] != NULL)
    {
        iLength++;
    }

    return iLength;
}

char* MyStrdup(const char* str)
{
    char* newStr;
    int strLength = MyStrlen(str);

    newStr = new char(strLength+1);

    for (register int i = 0; i < strLength; i++)
    {
        newStr[i] = str[i];
    }
    newStr[strLength] = NULL;

    return newStr;
}
```

Can someone note the place that makes it crash? I think it's a memory leak maybe.
Also, can you note things to improve in the code? For my learning purpose

EDIT: Thanks, I don't know why I used () instead of [] to define my new char[]. That was a memory leak or overwrite after all.

Comment: An important thing to learn is to reach first for `std::string`, and program with c++ idioms in general.

Comment: Besides the wrong use of `new`, You should deallocate the memory after printing s2 out using `delete[]`.

Comment: @ViktorSimkó, `delete[]`

Comment: @StoryTeller, Thanks

Comment: @StoryTeller I know, but my purpose was to recreate those functions.  What happens if I wont delete[]? After using strdup I should use delete[] too?

Comment: Do not use `delete` on anything returned from a `c` library function. The memory allocators are not guaranteed to be compatible.

Comment: Is there a way to make this so I the user of the function wont have to use delete after using the function? it makes it less user friendly isn't it?

Comment: And in general. RTFM. If a library functions allocate a resource, it will document how you should release it. You then use that, and only that, method on said resource.

Comment: Yes, it isn't particularly user friendly. That's why string classes that implement RAII came into existence. See my first comment on what is the best way IMHO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "new" statement for an array should be with square brackets:

```
newStr = new char[strLength+1];
```

When you do

```
new char(c)
```

It allocates a single character and copies the character c into it.
When you do

```
new char[n]
```

it allocates memory for n characters

Answer (score 4):

The expression `new char(strLength+1)` allocates a *single* character, and initializes it to `strLength + 1`. That of course means you will write out of bounds and have *undefined behavior* when you copy the string.

You should use `new char[strLength + 1]` instead, to allocate an "array" of characters.

---

On an unrelated note, while the terminating character in a string is commonly called the *null* character, it's not actually a null *pointer* (which is what `NULL` is for). Not that it really matters since in C++ `NULL` is a macro that expands to `0`, but you should probably be explicit and use `'\0'` anyway (it gives more context for future readers).

Comment: So, why did the program crash only in the second time I run it. As the memory overwrite was in the first run too

Comment: @Ofek.T. Undefined behavior is, by its very definition, undefined. And that includes sometimes *seemingly* working fine, and other times crashing without warning.